# Hats are back!! Get into the annual Winterbash! 456 users have earned 1354 hats thus far!

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions, winter-bash

The annual [Winterbash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) is on again, so grab your hats while you can!

Overall, [Travel is currently ranked 26th](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

Travel's own [leaderboard is visible here](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com).

Current top 5:

1. JonathanReez - **26** hats.
2. Mark Mayo - 23 hats.
3. Jan - 18 hats.
4. Zach Lipton - 16 hats.
5. dda - 16 hats.

Answer (score 3):

There are several places to look, the first is here: https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/
It tells you which hats are open knowledge, a few more are secret, and how to get those hats.

And you can go to places like [the big mega post about hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats).
There usually is also a chat room about the hats, this year it is [here.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69997/wb17)